# Use of predefined sounds in AudioServicesPlayAlertSound?

Tags: iphone, audio

Is it possible to use predefined sound ids in AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices) or can this cause my app to be rejected?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003263/are-we-allowed-to-use-default-system-sounds-in-third-party-apps