# Are we allowed to use default system sounds in third party apps?

Tags: iphone, ios

Are we allowed to use default system sounds(like message ringtone) in third party apps?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. From [the multimedia programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2)

> Note: System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface sound effects are not available to your application. For example, using the kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert constant as a parameter to the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound function will not play anything.

If you were allowed to use them, there would be an API for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you say:

"can we access chord.waw and play it directly"

my answer would be:

"no, there's no guarantee that the file actually exists on target machine, and I'm not even diggin into rights or other legal implications - if appliable".

If you say:

"can we emit the default system sound bind with a system event (eg: modal popup) ?"

my answer would be:

"Yes, system sounds are there for this reason, so our application will be coherent with the target system standard behaviour - and legal implication about rights on sound files would be entirely out of my application scope"

Forgive my bad english.

Comment: "Yes, system sounds are there for this reason, so our application will be coherent with the target system standard behaviour" - makes perfect sense, and I have no idea why this isn't allowed!

Comment: @jrturton May be because to avoid the user getting confused over if the alert sound was because I passed a level in angry birds or if an actual text was received.. :)